# Merge GeoJSON Files for School Districts

Tags: python, json, geojson, shapefile

I have 3 GeoJSON files containing school district borders.  Each file contains the data for a particular group of school districts (School_District_Unified.geojson, School_District_Elementary.geojson, School_District_Secondary.geojson).

[Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_du60FdL5nWdUlmYVZFMGV2VWs?usp=sharing) to the GeoJSON files here.

The script I am trying to use is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325030/merging-two-geojson-polygons-in-python), but not having success:

```
import json
import geojson
from functools import partial
import pyproj
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops

# reading into three geojson objects, in a GCS (WGS84)
with open('School_District_Elementary.geojson') as geojson1:
    poly1_geojson = json.load(geojson1)

with open('School_District_Secondary.geojson') as geojson2:
    poly2_geojson = json.load(geojson2)

with open('School_District_Unified.geojson') as geojson3:
    poly3_geojson = json.load(geojson3)

# pulling out the polygons
poly1 = shapely.geometry.asShape(poly1_geojson['features'][2]
['geometry'])
poly2 = shapely.geometry.asShape(poly2_geojson['features'][2]
['geometry'])
poly3 = shapely.geometry.asShape(poly3_geojson['features'][2]
['geometry'])

# checking to make sure they registered as polygons
print poly1.geom_type
print poly2.geom_type
print poly3.geom_type

# merging the polygons - they are feature collections, containing a 
# point, a polyline, and a polygon - I extract the polygon
# for my purposes, they overlap, so merging produces a single polygon 
# rather than a list of polygons
mergedPolygon = poly1.union(poly2)

# using geojson module to convert from WKT back into GeoJSON format
geojson_out = geojson.Feature(geometry=mergedPolygon, properties={})

# outputting the updated geojson file - for mapping/storage in its 
#GCS format
with open('Merged_Polygon.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(geojson_out.geometry, outfile, indent=3, 
encoding="utf-8")
outfile.close()

# reprojecting the merged polygon to determine the correct area
# it is a polygon covering much of the US, and derived from USGS 
#data, so using Albers Equal Area
project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:5070'))

mergedPolygon_proj = shapely.ops.transform(project,mergedPolygon)
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.dump(geojson_out.geometry, outfile, indent=3, encoding="utf-8")`

`json.dump` does not have an `encoding` parameter.

1) Remove encoding from the `json.dump` call.

```
json.dump(geojson_out.geometry, outfile, indent=3)
```

2) Change to use encoding in the file open

```
with open('Merged_Polygon.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(geojson_out.geometry, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: When using `with()`, the context manager, there's no need to `close()`.